# Extract Partial Matches From Table

Tags: excel

I have a table(_2020), and in ColumnE(Concat) I have two concatenated values, and I want to search a string(B1) in those values so it returns ColumnF(Winner).

I'm using this `COUNTIF(_2020[Concat];"*"&$B$1&"*")`

And then this `IF(A5>$C$1;"";INDEX(_2020[Winner];AGGREGATE(15;3;(ROW(_2020[Concat])-ROW(Matches!E2)+1)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1;_2020[Concat]));A5)))`

`A5` - Row Number;
`C1` - Count function;
Matches - Sheetname where the table is;
`E2` - First row of ColumnE;

It's not returning the correct rows.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was forgotting to F4 the Matches!E2.. :shame: xD